# How to use 'new' insted of 'malloc' in code

Tags: c++, malloc, type-conversion

My code is like below

```
SP->xs = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
```

where `xs` is the structure variable and `size` is `int` type,

so here how can I use `new` instead of `malloc`

which header file I should include ? and how this new line's syntax will become ?

I just tried it out as like below

```
SP->xs = operator new sizeof(double)*[size];
```

When I compile this code some error occur as below

```
error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'operator new' based on conversion to type 'double*'
error: expected ';' before 'sizeof'
```

as I newbie to C++ so I don't know much more details about it,

So please describe me that how to use `new` here in my code instead of `malloc`

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Consider getting a C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
SP->xs = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
```

is

```
SP->xs = new double[size];
```

This does not require any `#include`s.

To free the allocated array, use `delete[]`:

```
delete[] SP->xs;
```

The square brackets are important: without them, the code will compile but will have [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since you're writing in C++, consider using `std::vector<double>` instead of managing memory allocation by hand.

Comment: The two are not quite equivalent: `malloc( size * sizeof(double) )` has type `void*`, and will need a cast to assign it to a `double*`.  `new double[size]` is type safe.  (Since his initial code compiled, though, we can probably assume that `SP->xs` is a `void*`.  Or that he's compiling the code as C, in which case, nothing with `new` will work.)

Comment: And since he explicitly asked: you might add that you don't need to include anything to use the standard `new`.  (You do for placement new, but that's a step further in understanding C++.)